# How to get placeholder instead of label in wordpress comments.php?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, comments

I am using this code to display the default wordpress comments template:

```
<?php comments_template(); ?>
```

How can I change the name/email/url/comment label to a placeholder? 
I thought that I could modify the comment-template.php in the wp-includes folder or should I create a comments.php file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your theme has comments.php file then edit that file and write your placeholder there. otherwise create your own comments.php file and design your own comment form. here is the reference link.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form
or you can see comments.php file in any default theme like "twenty twelve" 
Cheeers!

Comment: But there are some specific links to functions, how about these? Sorry, I am a php noob :p